# What it takes for a Math department to develop a minor program in Statistics?

Tags: teaching

What it minimally takes for a Math department to develop a minor program in Statistics? Do the department require to have a major in area X to have a X minor?

Edit: How many courses at minimum does the department need to have a minor in Stats.  I see many departments requires students to take 5-6 Stats class to have a minor in Stats, so I thought if a department offers 5-6 Stats classes, can they develop a minor in Stats in general?  Are there any common rules one needs to follow to create a Stats minor, or any minor in general?

Comment: I think some context here would be incredibly useful.  Are you a student?  Professor?  TA?  Something else?

Comment: If your real question is the last sentence - "Can a department offer a minor in X and not a major in X" - the answer is "There are some departments that offer a minor in a subject in which they do not offer a major." But the titular question is not answerable given the level of detail you've provided.

Comment: Although on hold because it is unclear... the answer is "a lot!" It would take the prolonged work of several people competent in an area to develop a coherent minor program that is presentable. This kind of thing cannot be an afterthought. There might be an issue of accreditation, too. And "statistics" can sometimes be an eminently practically-oriented field, so your students would be expected to really do things, not just have a piece of paper! Your faculty would need to know... or be willing to hire several statisticians! No trivial answer here.

Comment: **Every university is different.**

Comment: @paulgarrett I share your assumption that this is a professor asking but I'm not entirely sure. Mostly because if it is a professor then why ask here?

Comment: @DavidKaye Some faculty are as clueless as anyone else, outside their specific competence, especially with regard to administrative issues.

Answer (score 2):

Other than my "context" comment above, this standard simply will not be the same at all schools.  Your best bet is to ask your department dean/chair who will either know the answer or where to find the answer.